# Geodjango django.contrib.gis.geos Linestring to Shapely Linestring

Tags: geodjango, shapely

I know its a basic problem, but I just got started with GIS and I'm badly stuck.

I tried to use a  `django.contrib.gis.geos import LineString` Linestring with a shapely function `shapely.ops.snap()`. Obviously its missing the attribute of the shapely object and I get a `AttributeError: 'LineString' object has no attribute '_geom'`

How do I turn the LineString into a shapely LineString and back into a geodjango geos LineString to save it to the database?

It seems a bit weird as well as the docs say its both a GEOS geometry and interchangable(https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/GEOSGeometry) but it seems it is not.

Feeling bad to ask this but I'm not finding the appropriate function and the docs seem a bit more minimalistic than what I'm used to (even though the libraries seem great) :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after fiddling around way too long as expected, Properties of GEOS geometry in geodjango are described here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/)

The object can outputted as for example `wkt` by calling `.wkt` on it and then loaded.
SO:

```
from shapely import wkt 

geodjangoGeometryAsWkt = GeodjangoObject.wkt
shapelyGeom = wkt.loads(geodjangoGeometryAsWkt)
```